# Counting the number of lines through a given set of points, some of which are collinear

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

What does counting total number of lines mean? What type of lines does it include?

Especially I'm very confused about collinear points. Like in this example,  below.

> Consider $10$ points on a plane out, of which $4$ are collinear. Find the total number of lines that can be drawn through those points.

(Actually everywhere) they say that lines are $ \space C(10,2)-C(4,2)+1$.
I can understand why $C(10,2)$ is done, but why $C(4,2)$ and $-1$.

Everywhere they say that $C({4,2})$ are lines made by collinear points so we have to subtract them and the we add $1$ because we have also subtracted the mainline.

What does all this mean?? Please explain with a physical context and simple to understand language.

Answer (score 2):

Because as there are $4$ points collinear, then in the $4$ points that are collinear, we can choose two points, then there are $C^4_2$ ways to make lines from the four points. *But* the $C^4_2$ lines are the same! So we have to subtract $C^4_2$. *But* there is a problem again! We subtracted all the lines joining the four collinear points! As every line has to be counted once, but this is not, we have to add $1$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why are the lines same

Comment: Collinear means that three or more points lies on the same line.

Comment: So what consider  these  dashes are 4 points  - - - - now 1st and 2nd dash make one line so does 1st and 3rd so does 1st and fourth so why do we need to subtract these

Comment: Try reading https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collinearity

Comment: @Vibhav "*so why do we need to subtract these*"  Suppose you are at a party with adam, twenty guys named bob, and culver and you ask yourself "how many different names did I see here?"  We saw a guy named adam, so thats one.  We saw a guy named culver, so thats another.  Now, we also want to include the fact that we heard the name "bob" but we only want to include it once so that we got a total of three names we heard.  Now... suppose instead that I know there are 20 bobs in attendance and everyone else has a different name and I counted that there were 30 people.  How many names? 30-20+1.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways to select a pair of points.

In the event that no three or more of the points all lied on the same line, then all $\binom{10}{2}$ of these would have resulted in distinct lines.  That is not the case for us however.  We are told that four of our points are colinear.

We want to count that line that the four colinear points lie on exactly once, but we had accidentally counted it $\binom{4}{2}$ times in the above.  So, to correct our count, we can subtract $(\binom{4}{2}-1)$ from the total to remove the number of times that we counted it too much leaving us as having counted that line exactly once as desired.

Comment: Can u reiterate the first line of ur second paragraph i.e we want to count....

Comment: @Vibhav For each choice of two of our points, we can draw a line between them.  If we were told that no three or more of our points were colinear, then each of those lines we could have been drawn would have been unique and different.  There are $\binom{10}{2}$ ways that we could choose two points to draw a line between.  We are told however that four of our points are colinear, which by definition means that the line connecting any two of those points are in fact the same line.

Comment: means u want to say line connecting point 1 and 3 is same as line connecting 1 and 4

Comment: If points 1,2,3,4 are the four colinear points in question, yes, as well as the line connecting points 2 and 3, or connecting 2 and 4, etc...

Comment: BUt why, they all represent different lines having diffrent lengths

Comment: @Vibhav  You are confusing lines with line segments.  Line segments have finite lengths, but lines are infinite.

Comment: OH thanks i completely forgot that in consideration.